# Can I assume all valid HTML entities will display correctly in all modern browers and devices?

Tags: php, browser, html-entities, device, mobile-devices

I sometimes like to use unusual symbols in my web pages, such as `&#8281;` (which should display as a 5-dot symbol like the 5 on a die) and `&#9883;` (which should display as a pictogram of an atom). I also like to use whitespace characters like `&#8202;` (hair space) and `&#8239;` (narrow nonbreaking space).

Can I just take it for granted that all modern browsers (and not-so-modern like IE-8) and various phones and tablets can display these properly?

Or is there some code I can use to check and then substitute something more standard if that character is not displayable?  What I have in mind would be "If this character isn't available, use this instead."

I tried to write that in PHP like this:

```
$symbol = ("&#8281;") ? "&#8281;" : "::";
```

But of course that won't work, because any such string in quotes is truthy. Without the quotes it throws an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you can't assume that. You could make a condition to detect the current browser with jquery and change values.

Comment: Thanks, @Gabriel. I think you're right that I can't assume the entities will work. That's why I'd like a way to test. But identifiying the browsers isn't practical, since there are a lot of phones and other devices out there which won't all have the same capabilities. Even if I knew that some Motorola or Samsung phone used a specific browser, I wouldn't know that a particular HTML entitiy would display properly on it.